# The specified key does not exist. while accessing file from the GCS through Signed Url

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

```
// This method is used to return the signed URL , After getting the URL I can able to view the //preview of the file which is in GCS, But in my case signed URL is not working its throwing the below //Exception while accessing in the browser. How to resolve this issue?




        BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(BlobId.of(bucketName, gcsFolderPrefix + fullFileName)).build();
        URL url = storage.signUrl(blobInfo, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES, Storage.SignUrlOption.withV4Signature());

        return url;

//Exception
```

//    This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is //shown below.

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Details>No such object: google storage location</Details>
</Error>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that your file does not exist up within the GCS bucket.
Please double check the path that you tried to retrieve.

Can you download that file using `gsutil`?

Comment: for some reasons , it seems that it can not find this file `sur-63418-dev-ext-1/ASK/SGT/DOCUMENT/27/38`, check the name of the file, I think you should add the `/fileName.ext`

Comment: can you download that file `gsutil cp gs://sur-63418-dev-ext-1/ASK/SGT/DOCUMENT/27/38/d413146___.pdf  .`, run this command in the `google cloud shell`

Comment: i can able to download it from the dev environment,

Comment: Do i need to add the content type to generate the Signed Url

Comment: According to the Cloud Storage [Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#contenttype), if you do not specify a content type when you upload an object, the Cloud Storage system defaults to application/octet-stream when it serves the object. Said that, it means, content-type header is not required to generate the Signed URL.

Comment: Actually i can able to download the file from GCS, but the requirement is to preview pdf file using signed URL, Any modifications is needed to my existing code.

Comment: After hitting the signed url in the browser its should preview the .pdf file

Comment: I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your file is a .pdf file, you will need to update the metadata of your blob in Google Cloud Storage before generating the SignedUrl.

```
BlobInfo blobinfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(BlobId.of(bucketName, gcsFolderPrefix + fullFileName))
//Add the correct content type
.setContentType("application/pdf")
.build();

// Update the Blob
storage.update(blobinfo);

URL url = storage.signUrl(blobInfo, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES,Storage.SignUrlOption.withV4Signature());
```

To preview a .pdf file, the file has to be downloaded first and then you will able to see it.

In case you only want to view the file in the browser, you should indicate to the browser that the file should be viewed in the browser and so the HTTP *response* should include the following headers:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.pdf"
```

By searching in the [**BlobInfo.Builder** class of Google Cloud Storage Java API](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-storage/latest/com/google/cloud/storage/BlobInfo.Builder.html#setContentDisposition-java.lang.String-), we can set the Content-Type and Content-Disposition as following in Java:

```
BlobInfo blobinfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(BlobId.of(bucketName, gcsFolderPrefix + fullFileName))
//Add the correct content type
.setContentType("application/pdf")
.setContentDisposition("inline")
.build();

// Update the Blob
storage.update(blobinfo);

URL url = storage.signUrl(blobInfo, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES,Storage.SignUrlOption.withV4Signature());
```

To have the file *downloaded* rather than viewed:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.pdf"
```

```
BlobInfo blobinfo = BlobInfo.newBuilder(BlobId.of(bucketName, gcsFolderPrefix + fullFileName))
//Add the correct content type
.setContentType("application/pdf")
.setContentDisposition("attachment")
.build();

// Update the Blob
storage.update(blobinfo);

URL url = storage.signUrl(blobInfo, 15, TimeUnit.MINUTES,Storage.SignUrlOption.withV4Signature());
```